# ValidationSummary showing for fields that are not in page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I created a login page based on the user model, the user has additional required fields apart from username and password (e.g. e-mail address) but I'm only displaying username and password for login.

The problem is that if I leave username and/or password empty, the ModelState is getting error messages for all fields within the Model class, resulting in misleading validation messages.

The code for the view is:

```
<div class="form-login">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2 class="form-signin-title">Login</h2>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-medium btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
}
```

The validation summary is part of the _Layout, and is only displayed if the model is not valid.

Is there a way I can show a validation summary for the controls on screen only?

Comment: Putting your validation summary in your _Layout will no doubt create you more pain than it's worth. Just put it in the corresponding views you need it in.

Comment: @mattytommo - I have created a summary on each view. Not that I'm doubting you, but why would it add more pain than it's worth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation error messages show up because asp.net MVC validation validates the view model. So it does not matter if you display a field in the view or not because the model as a whole is validated. You should use a dedicated view model for this form that does only contain the fields displayed.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue.

What's the best practice for ViewModels, have them in a separate folder, or within the controller folder/controller class?

Comment: I'm adding them in a model sub folder ViewModels because they are related to models. MVC Music Store (http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) adds ViewModels to a ViewModels folder in the root. I'd add them to a location where you'll find them when you open the solution in one year...